# Ratcliff-Obershelp string similarity

Tags: algorithm, recursion, pattern-matching, similarity

I need to implement the **Ratcliff-Obershelp** (aka Gestalt Pattern Matching) algorithm and I'm stuck at building the recursive part.

I have built the lcs (longest common substring) intermediate function (using dynamic programming), now i need to apply it to the 2 compared strings.

Example:

```
lcs("WIKIMEDIA", "REMEDY") = "MED"
```

Taking both sides (left-right) of each string, the new string chunks to compare:

```
("WIKI", "RE") and ("IA", "Y");
```

both return lcs = 0, but i need to implement this in an recursive way, as the 2 initial strings may result in 4 chunks to "lcs"-compare, and then 8, etc.

The exit condition would be either "lcs = 0" or "one of the strings is empty" (preferred over the former condition)
Any pseudo code would help.
Thanks!

Comment: difflib has already implemented this and it's highly efficient, you might have take a look at the source code on how they implemented that, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py#L629 , if you never heard of difflib, see few examples of it here https://www.kite.com/python/docs/difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio